# Can I use my iphone charger to charge my kindle?

Tags: kindle

Can I use my iphone charger to charge a kindle

Answer (score 2):

I use the Kindle USB cable with the iPhone wall adapter (US-style plug). It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you attach a USB cable, you can charge with the iPhone charger everyting.